# Couldn´t hande App Crash on a SocketStream if the Connection accidently drops

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, uwp

I´ve got a Little tool for easy transferring files from my mobile phone (Windows 10) to the PC. just a file, quick, without wire, without searching through Folders. just "share with" > and all other Client will Show the file for download. First with an Internet-Server as "Cache". Now I´m extending this idea to WLAN/LANs. I´ve chosen to Build an own solution without HTTP, or FTP. Just Bytes over TCP/IP. First test solution works  well. I played a lot with buffers, sizes, continuous streams. I also found a nice Little method in the GarbageCollector - now my old, slow Lumia 640 Transfers the biggest files WITHOUT running out of Memory (using 33MB max before 150 to out_of_memory and the perfect buffer size gets this phone to my WLANs max. Transfer rate. cant believe it,

but there is one Thing I counldn´t handle..

IF THE CONNECTION DROPS ACCIDENTLY THIS LINE IN THE RECEIVING PART OF THE APP WILL FORCE
     AN TaskAwaiter exception, IMMEDIATELY, looks like much faster than I could handle it. I tried everthing using the sync variant, the async, Task.Run() , TaskFactory.RunAsync. I´ve never seen an UWP-App crashing SO FAST 
the "inStream" is based on the accidental socketconnection, and the Excep. throws on the .CopyToAsync().

How to handle the TaskAwaiter Exception itself or is there an other way?

```
private async void SocketListener_ConnectionReceived(Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            socketListener.ConnectionReceived -= SocketListener_ConnectionReceived;
            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                tb_status.Text = "incoming Connection... receiving the file... Please wait until it´s done....";
            });
            try
            {
                Stopwatch stoppUhr = new Stopwatch();
                stoppUhr.Start();

                Stream inStream = args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
                StorageFile outFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.CreateFileAsync("theTestFile.wav", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                Stream fileWriteStream = await outFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
```

HERE IS THE CASE Exception rises on this line, at the copy - Task

```
await inStream.CopyToAsync(fileWriteStream);
fileWriteStream.Dispose();
inStream.Dispose();

double elapsedSeconds = stoppUhr.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
stoppUhr.Stop();
stoppUhr = null;
double recSizeMB = (await outFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync()).Size / 1024 / 1024;
double mBitPerSec = recSizeMB * 8 / elapsedSeconds;
```

Comment: What's the exception details?  Can [this document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn263240(v=win.10)) helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IT WAS A WINDOWS PREVIEW-Problem.... :) THX for Your HELP :) **

In a few days my app has it´s fist alpha-Launch :))
[QuickTransfer for OneDrive and LAN / WLAN (W10 UWP) - future-STORE link](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh40m62)

[for You :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5U72.png)